# Circuit for squaring (raise to power 2) signal

Tags: circuit-design

I have a voltage signal and I want to design a circuit that can do squaring of this signal ( raise it to power 2).
For example when I read the output, instead of having 2 V I get 2^2= 4 V.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Consider something related to the MC1496?

Comment: Here's a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373492/analog-analog-multiplication-part-of-a-hybrid-cpu-for-fun) I asked before about analog multiplication, I believe the answers will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [analogue multiplier](http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-079.pdf)r (basically a kind of VCA) and apply the signal to both inputs. Take care about headroom though.